# Movie Database, storing multiple genres

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, join, many-to-many

I'm trying to build a database that will store information on movies.

```
    Title
    Plot
    Genre
    Rating
    Director
```

The only thing that is bothering me is that most films don't just have one genre and I'm struggling to figure out how to store this on a MySQL Database. At first I was thinking that I'll just have one table and store all the genres in one column, separating them by a comma and when I want to retrieve them separate them using PHP, but I'm not sure this is the best way as I think I would have trouble sorting and searching for a specific genre e.g. Horror when the collumn contains 'Horror, Thriller, Action'.

Comment: don't forget that films can have http://www.filmsite.org/subgenres.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest you should follow the following structure:

> tablename: movies
>
> movieid, title, plot, rating, director

```
> sample data:
> 
> 1 titanic Bollywood   10  James Cameron
```

> tablename: genres
>
> genreid, genre

```
> sample data:
>  1    Horror
>  2    Thriller
>  3    Action
>  4    Love
```

> tablename: moviegenres
>
> moviegenresid, movieid, genreid

```
> sample data:
> 1 1   2
> 2 1   4
```

And the query is:

```
select m.*,group_concat(g.genre)
from movies m inner join moviegenres mg
on m.movieid=mg.movieid
inner join genres g
on g.genreid=mg.genreid
group by m.movieid
;
```

See the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6922d/6)

Comment: I would agree with this answer except for the creation of the arbitrary UIDs `genreID` and `movieID`. In a relational database, having an extra arbitrary key is costly because instead of maintaining and guaranteeing uniqueness of 1 natural key (e.g. `genre`), now you have to maintain 2 unique keys (`genre` AND `genreID`). Unless you have a very good reason to do this, it is unnecessary and costly. Avoiding this also means you no longer need that extra table `genres`, further reducing the cost of maintenance (read: increasing the speed) of a relational database.

Answer (score 10):

What you are looking to model here is called a "many-to-many" relationship, and is very common when modelling "real world" categorisations.

There are many descriptions out there of how to work with such relationships including:

- Praveen's answer here which is specific to your question.
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table - the extra table linking two populations in many/may relationships is usually called an intersection table or junction table.
- http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php which helpfully shows an example with the table and key/constraints design, a handy data representation diagram in case that isn't clear, and how the relationship is modelled and used in the application.
- Any good database design book/tutorial will cover this somewhere.

Do not be tempted to skip the extra intersection table by storing multiple genres in one field for each film (a comma separated list for instance). This is a very common "anti pattern" that *will* cause you problems, maybe not today, maybe not tomorrow, but eventually. I recommend anyone working with database design give Bill Karwin's "SQL Antipatterns" (http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) a read. It is written in a way that should be accessible to a relative beginner, but contains much that those of us who should know better need reminding of from time to time (many-to-many relations, the list-in-a-field solution/problem, and what you should do instead, are one of the first things the book covers).

Answer (score 5):

## This answer is an elaboration of my comment on @Praveen Prasannan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17520721/7560187) above.

I would eliminate the arbitrary surrogate keys `movieID` and `genreID` as a way to remove unnecessary overhead for the relational database. Since `title` and `genre` are natural unique keys, we should use them and not ask the database to maintain the uniqueness of extra, meaningless keys and tables (the `genres` table in the referenced answer). This should improve the speed and performance for large relational databases and is good practice.

> tablename: movies

> primary key: title

> title, plot, rating, director

```
> sample data:
> Titanic  Bollywood   10  James Cameron
```

> tablename: moviegenres

> primary key: title, genre

> title, genre

```
> sample data:
> Titanic   Thriller
> Titanic   Romance
```

This also makes queries a lot easier for both the user and the machine since you don't have to join an extra table to decode the genres by the arbitrary UID.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit late, but I made a simple code from the top comment code above

```
select movieid, title, plot, rating, director, group_concat(genre)
from movies
natural join moviegenres
natural join genres;
```