# Creating a SQL movie database. Do I really a "genre_linker" table for the relationship between "movies" and "genres"

Tags: mysql

I am building an sql movie database for all the dvds and blurays I own. I currently have the following tables...

movies(id(primary key), title, year, format, runtime)
people(id(primary key), gender, dob, dod, name)
credits(person_id(foreign key), movie_id(foreign key), job, role)
genres(id(primary key), genre)
movie_genres(movie_id(foreign key), genre_id(foreign key))

My question is do I need/is there a logical benefit i.e. memory management etc. to having 2 separate tables for the genres or would it be better to just have 1 say like....

genres(movie_id(foreign key), genres)

Answer (score 0):

The movies_genres table is a mapping table to create a many to many relationship. That way you can have many movies associated with many genres and vice versa.

Comment: Is this that advantageous over a one to many as I described? It just seems redundant to me to have 2 tables where 1 would suffice.

Comment: If im understanding correct an example of many to many would be something like this....             Genres
10 | "action"
11 | "scifi"
12 | "thriller"

Movie_genres
267 | 10
267 | 11
267 | 12

Vs a one to many like this... 

Genres
267 | "action"
267 | "scifi"
267 | "thriller"

Comment: An example of using a mapping table like this enables you to link movie 1 to genres A, B, and C; movie 2 to genres B, C, F. Flip that around and genre B is associated to movies 1 and 2.  In other words, a movie can be associated with as many genres as needed and a genre can be associated with as many movies as needed. That cannot happen with just one table. With one table you will limited to either associating one genre to a movie or one movie to a genre.

Answer (score 0):

Your final suggestion of using `genres(movie_id(foreign key), genres)` is probably the worst option of all as you have an additional join to get to a column which could just as easily be stored in the movies table. That really would be overhead for the sake of overhead.

If you are determined ​to drop the many-to-many you could store the genres directly in your movies table but a comma separated list of string values for genres would be very inefficient in terms of storage and querying. You could store the list of genres in a SET column in the movies table. This would use a fraction of the storage and can be queried very efficiently.

Both the many-to-many and SET options are widely used for this specific use case. I would opt for the many-to-many as it is the normalised form and easier to manage.

Comment: Can you please explain how that would require an additional join? I was thinking it would be one less since its only joining 2 tables instead of 3? Or are you saying at that point its no different than just a comma separated list in the movies table?

Comment: It would be additional in that there would be no benefit over it being stored directly in the movies table (as it is a one-to-one relationship). Whether in your proposed separate table or the movies table, a comma separated list of values is bad news unless it is never going to be used as a search criterion.

Comment: Here's a link to a previous post on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520720/movie-database-storing-multiple-genres/17520722

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you